# Ignore case of the delimiter in C# Split function

Tags: c#

Is there a way to ignore case of the delimiter while splitting a string?

Example:

```
string sampleInput = @"String validation: **OrbitaryValue**=z:\Somepth\Somename\SQL";
```

If split by orbitary value, the split should ignore case of the delimiter "OrbitrayValue".

Regex is not an option in my case, so the solutions provided for the other question won't suit my scenarion

Comment: not getting you ....

Comment: on what basis you want to split ...

Comment: Read [ask], search before asking a question.

Comment: `Split` doesn't have a way ignore case, but `IndexOf` does, so you can use that in a loop to find the delimiters and `Substring` to get the tokens.

Comment: Use a ToLower() on the string and split after it.

Comment: @juharr Thanks this is what exactly I was looking for. How can I mark this as an answer?

Comment: @karthik It's not an answer.  If you find the duplicate useful up vote it and the answer or answers you find useful there.